# Как закачать вложенные папки на s3 c помощью aws cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

Использую команду
aws s3 cp  home/user/testdir $s3_path --recursive

Должна поидее закачивать все что находится в папке testdir
но по итогу закачивает только файлы из самой директории. Папки игнорирует, как закачать вместе с вложенными папками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как пишут [здесь](https://serverfault.com/q/682708/292034), если пунктом назначения указан корень *bucket-а*, то будут скопированы только файлы из указанного каталога:

```
$ aws s3 cp --recursive /home/user/testdir s3://bucket/
```

а если указать каталог, то будет скопировано всё дерево файлов/каталогов:

```
$ aws s3 cp --recursive /home/user/testdir s3://bucket/testdir
```

Comment: Да, вы правы!))

Comment: @Dofri, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).